# Any tool that can identify and match two voices?

Tags: python, audio, audio-recording, artificial-intelligence, audio-editing

Let's say we have 5 audio files as A.mp3, B.mp3, C.mp3, D.mp3, E.mp3. supposed that A and E are recorded by the same person, John, with ~98-100 % matched. On the other hand, B.mp3 was recorded by John's brother, Lee. where with ~60-70 % matched to A.mp3 and E.mp3, but B.mp3 and C.mp3 are ~98-100% matched since they were recorded by the same person Lee.

Any tool that we can help us identify this kind of issue ? We put 5 audio files and mark the ones with the highest matched with score.

Comment: Is it the person peaking you wish to detect (John/Lee)? Or that the audio was recorded on the same devices (owned by John/Lee)?